# #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'examination'

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get examination date, value of test and test name in one SQL statement. I am able to do it in two stages, but not in one.  When I try to combine it I get an error as it say on the title.

here is the SQL statement that producing error:

```
select date, value, tname from examination, testresults, testname
LEFT JOIN examtype ON examtype.etype_id = examination.etype_id
LEFT JOIN examination ON examination.examination_id =  testresults.examination_id
LEFT JOIN testname ON testname.tname_id = testresults.tname_id
where examination.patientnhs_no= '1001001002' 
    and  date > '2008/09/05' 
    and examtype.name like 'blood%' 
    and testname.name like'tsh%' 
order by date asc 
limit 1
```

Comment: inner join with `examination` and again `left join` with `examination` ? Did not understand it how ever when you join same table multiple time you need to provide unique alias. `date,value and tname` are from which tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have listed the table examination two times, yet you did not give it an alias. 
Once in the FROM clause and once in a LEFT JOIN. 
You probally ment for

```
LEFT JOIN examination
```

to be

```
LEFT JOIN testresults
```

with testresults and testname removed after the FROM. (See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)).

The following should work (I have not tested it).

```
select date, value, tname from examination
                LEFT JOIN examtype ON examtype.etype_id = examination.etype_id
                LEFT JOIN testresults ON examination.examination_id =  testresults.examination_id
                LEFT JOIN testname ON testname.tname_id = testresults.tname_id
                where examination.patientnhs_no= '1001001002' and  date > '2008/09/05' and examtype.name like 'blood%' and testname.name like'tsh%' order by date asc limit 1
```